# Tkinter, оптимизация разрешения окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Писал олимпиадную задачу, и вот возникла проблема. Если запускать программу на разных операционных системах (или мониторах) интерфейс часто ломается.

Возможно, есть какие-то путь оптимизации окна? Можно ли задать значения параметров `width` и `height` в процентах от расширения монитора, или что-то вроде этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути, подобной возможности нет. Но можно узнать расширение монитора пользователя и указать какой либо процент от него. Например, окно с расширением в 80% от монитора:

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
x = root.winfo_screenwidth()  # размер  по горизонтали
y = root.winfo_screenheight()  # размер по вертикали

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(int(x*0.8), int(y*0.8))) # обязательно должно быть целое число

tkinter.mainloop()
```